# How to redirect the output from my file deletions and directory removals?

Tags: batch-file

I want to append the results after I remove the .txt files and the the CIS153 directory from my code.

The problem is that it is not appending the correct results.

I found out how to append the results to a text file I am just not sure where I should place that code for my script.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET CURRENT_DIR=%CD%
SET DIR_NAME=%CURRENT_DIR%CIS153
SET COUNTER=1

MKDIR %DIR_NAME% ECHO output.txt

FOR F DELIMS= %%X IN (MyData.txt) DO (
ECHO %%X  CUsersAdministratorDesktopCIS153myFile!COUNTER!.txt
SET A COUNTER=!COUNTER!+1
)

DEL CUsersAdministratorDesktopCIS153.txt | echo 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153 > output.txt

RD S CUsersAdministratorDesktopCIS153 | echo 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153 > output.txt
```

**I expect this code to output in the output.txt file.**

```
" C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>DEL 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153\*.txt

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>RD /S "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153"
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153, Are you sure (Y/N)? "
```

**Instead the output im receiving in the output.txt file is this**

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CIS153"
```

Comment: In the script you have posted there are really only two lines which I would not ask you to fix, `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `)`, all of the others have issues or would be better advised to be improved. It appears as if your `For` loop is supposed to create a new file each containing the content of a line and numbered according to that line, the rest is a mystery. As your code makes no sense, I would suggest that you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55905614/edit), to fix it, and whilst your at it, please tell us exactly what the code is supposed to be doing too!

Comment: Sorry, the first part is completed I just wanted to show the output of when I deleted the file into a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, **your fundamentals are incorrect**.

Here is some reading you can do regarding [redirecting output](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php).

If you run a .bat from the command line and redirect the output to a text file then you can replicate what you are trying to achieve. Example:

```
@echo off
:: Everything you put here won't display in the output file
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do set /a myVar%%i=!random!

@echo on
:: Everything you put here will display in the output file

for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do echo. !myVar%%i!
```

Run on the command line via `test.bat > output.txt` would leave an `output.txt` of:

```
C:\Test>for /L %i in (1 1 3) do echo. !myVar%i! 

C:\Test>echo. !myVar1! 
 11828

C:\Test>echo. !myVar2! 
 30270

C:\Test>echo. !myVar3! 
 19262
```